# Get all child models from parent Many to Many relationship Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am building an ecommerce website using Laravel 5.8 and have the following problem. I want to retrieve all products from a category and its child categories, but to be able to perform filtering queries afterwards in my code. For example price limits and quantitative availability on the products.

The store has categories, which have child categories in the same table.
Categories table (Simplified) - **id|name|parent_id** - Where if parent_id != 0, then the category is considered a child to a main category.

The products can be in more than one category and therefore I'm using a many to many relationship.
Products table (Simplified) - **id|name...**
Product categories table - **id|product_id|category_id**

My Products model look like this:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\CatalogCategory', 
        'catalog_product_categories', 
        'product_id', 
        'category_id'
    );
}
```

And my Categories model:

```
public function allProducts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\CatalogProduct', 
        'catalog_product_categories', 
        'category_id', 
        'product_id'
    )
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->whereDate('active_from', '<=', Carbon::now('Europe/Sofia'))
        ->where(function ($query)
        {
            $query->whereDate('active_to', '>=', Carbon::now('Europe/Sofia'))
                ->orWhereNull('active_to');
        })
        ->wherePivotIn('category_id', $this->allChildrenIds());;  
}
```

Currently doing this, returns an empty collection:

```
$category = CatalogCategory::find(3);
dd($category->allProducts);
```

Comment: Defined relationship is named `products` so it should be accessed as `$category->products;` - not allProducts isn't it

Comment: My bad, haven't copied it properly. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I guess the problem is `->wherePivotIn('category_id', $this->allChildrenIds())`.

You are trying to get products for a category - corresponding records can be identified by a row in pivot table which has this category's id with various other product_id.

But the wherePivotIn doesn't contain current category's id in `$this->allChildrenIds()` so no records are returned.

Define the relation without the wherePivotIn

```php
public function allProducts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\CatalogProduct', 
        'catalog_product_categories', 
        'category_id', 
        'product_id'
    )
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->whereDate('active_from', '<=', Carbon::now('Europe/Sofia'))
        ->where(function ($query)
        {
            $query->whereDate('active_to', '>=', Carbon::now('Europe/Sofia'))
                ->orWhereNull('active_to');
        });  
}
```

Then to get all products for current category and all it's subcategories

```php
$category = Category::with(['products', 'subcategories.products'])->get();
```

With this query the products associated with subcategories will be nested under each subcategory respectively.

Comment: This works, but is there a way to get all the products in one collection with some query? I need to have the ability to query the products for price ranges and get count aggregates

Comment: One easy way to get all products in a single collection will be to make two queries: first query all categories with subcategories and pluck the id's. The use these ids in 2nd query to get all products where the category_id is in the array of ids, then you can tack on other where conditions for price ranges